# XSLT filtering : How to apply XSLT filtering for RTF field across all the schemas in one go

Tags: web8.5, xslt, filtering-xslt

Using Web8.5, There is a requirement to do XSLT filtering for RTF field.
I am able to apply xslt filtering  in one schema for RTF field successfully.

However, looking for an option to do it for all the schema(>50) in one go.
Is it possible from CM? Please suggest the best way to apply XSLT filtering for all the schema's on RTF field?

Comment: Can you try using core services ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rich text formatting options are the same across Schemas (or "schema," if @DomCronin is following) you could consider embedding the same rich text format area field and its XSLT filter options where needed.

You would still need to use this field in your various schemas , but changes would be centralized and managed within a single field.

This is more challenging if content is already created, but either way, Components needs to be updated in order to (re)apply the filtering to existing content.

Comment: Thank you @Alvin. Agree with you. I can try this option.

Comment: @Alvin - we usually refer to XML Schemas rather than the arguably more correct, but insufferably pedantic "schemata". :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Tridion doesn't offer a way to apply this xslt to all rich text fields in all schemas at once.
The only solution I see is to write a tool  / script that uses the core service to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

We have a small set of 4 rich text embeddable schema, each with their own xslt and configuration of editor controls.

Any schema requiring rich text will embed one of these.

It is then much easier to manage the "richness" of editorial experience of the different types for the specific use cases of the front end design.

There are two approaches for managing this in your MVC models.

1. Create your embedded Richtext schema with the same rootnamespace

OR

2. Use semantic mapping in your rich text model

Comment: Thank you @Chris. Yes, I am going to try this option.